# Implement OAuth1 GET request into Nodejs and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, axios, postman

I would like to implement the following information into my GET request below into my React website using Axios, JavaScript, node.

Get request URL: https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/Search/General.xml?category=0124-0424-&condition=Used&sort_order=ExpiryDesc

```
Type: OAuth 1.0
SignatureMethod: PlainText
ConsumerKey: CK
ConsumerSecret: CS
AccessToken: AT
TokenSecret: TS
```

add authorization data to request headers

I have got this so far:

```
 Axios.request({
    url: "-url-",
    method: "GET",
    baseURL: "-baseurl-",
    auth: {
      username: "myUsername", // This is the client_id
      password: "myPassword" // This is the client_secret
    },
    data: {
      "grant_type": "client_credentials",
      "scope": "public"    
    }
  }).then(respose => {
    console.log(respose);  
  });
```

Comment: Is there anything specific we can help you with? I see you have gotten into the request, but I do not see any uh issue with the code so far.

Comment: Yes I dont know where to add the Type: OAuth 1.0 SignatureMethod: PlainText ConsumerKey: CK ConsumerSecret: CS AccessToken: AT TokenSecret: TS

Comment: That will depend on what you are actually requesting. Some apis will want you to include that in the AUTH header, others in the BODY as json, or others as XML. What API are you working with?

Comment: Im working with an api in new zealand called TradeMe, they want that included in the Authorisation tab on postman.

Comment: I have got it all running on postman no issues.

Comment: You cannot send a request body (`data`) with GET requests in any browser runtime environment

Answer (score 0):

Ok you cannot send something like that in uh plaintext. What you are doing right now the snippet you included, that looks like OAuth2 (I may be wrong)

but to use OAuth 1 you need a node.js library.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const OAuth = require('oauth-1.0a');


const oauth = OAuth({
  consumer: {
    key: 'CK',
    secret: 'CS',
  },
  signature_method: 'PLAINTEXT',
  hash_function(base_string, key) {
    return key;
  },
});

// OAuth 1.0 token
const token = {
  key: 'AT (replace this part)',
  secret: 'TS (replace this part)',
};


const url = 'url-endpoint';
const requestData = {
  url,
  method: 'GET',
};

// Generate OAuth 1.0 headers
const headers = oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(requestData, token));


axios({
  method: 'get',
  url,
  headers: {
    Authorization: headers['Authorization'],
  },
})
  .then(response => {

    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

So yes, this is complicated.